# jQuery - click and addclass triggering another (related) click?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I'm creating a menu. Menu is below.

```
$('.category').mouseover(function() { $(this).removeClass('category').addClass('categoryhover'); }).mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass('categoryhover').addClass('category'); });
$('.category').click(function() { $('.catmenu').removeClass('catmenu').addClass('hide'); $('.categoryact').removeClass('categoryact').addClass('category'); $('.hide', this).removeClass('hide').addClass('catmenu'); $(this).removeClass('category').addClass('categoryact'); });
$('.categoryact').live('click', function() { $('.catmenu').removeClass('catmenu').addClass('hide'); $(this).removeClass('categoryact').addClass('category'); });
```

Clicking on a div with the category category will give that category a new class (categoryact) and show its submenu. Presumably clicking it again will hide it. However, when the event that gives the clicked div its new class (categoryact), the function to hide it is also triggered. The result of course is that the first click, to show the submenu, appears to do nothing. Of course we know its actually firing the other one.

Can someone tell me why its triggering the "hide" functionality, and a possible way to fix it? Or damn, a way to write this simpler. There's a lot of add/remove-Class going on. ;)

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier by using jQuery's toggle() and toggleClass() functions? http://api.jquery.com/toggle, http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass ... that way, you might not need a live() binding at all, as simple click() would toggle the class and the submenu

Comment: Is there a way to do add the hover effects in CSS? In my experience, that is the simplest. Maybe post the html and the css and we can help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5EkZm/ try this hope that it helps...

Comment: @Smejko I'll have to see if that works for what I'm doing here. Thanks. @rcravens: No, for this particular project the hover effect in CSS will not work **properly**. Using CSS for hover was actually what I did first. @3nigma: Thanks. :) I'll see how that works if I can't get toggle to work properly.

Comment: @Smejko: I don't know how I didn't catch toggle() before, but it's exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: Guys, put answers down below--y'know, as answers.

Comment: well, it was just a suggestion from me, not a real answer... but here you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(copied over from comments, so an answer can be accepted)

wouldn't it be easier by using jQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) functions? ... that way, you might not need a live() binding at all, as simple click() would toggle the class and the submenu

Comment: Thanks, now I can upvote + accept. Your suggestion was actually the kick in the pants I needed to get my back on track. So it ended up being the answer. :)